# How to create a event to trigger when all plugins have been initiated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, optimization

I have a ajax navigation my website. 
So not to have a js script for each section of the page, I have chosen to create a single js which contains all the necessary code to minimize the HTTP request.

Then I coded something like:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" data-pageindex="0">Home</a>
<a href="#" data-pageindex="1">Contact</a>
<a href="#" data-pageindex="2">Portfolio</a>

<div id="page-home"></div>
<div id="page-contact"></div>
<div id="page-portfolio"></div>
```

**JS**

```
var urls = ['home', 'contact', 'portfolio'];    

$("[data-pageindex]").on("click", function(e){
    var index = parseInt($(this).data("pageindex"));

    load_section(index);

    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

function load_section(index_load){

    var id_section = "#page-" + urls[index_load]; 

    if (! isEmpty( $(id_section) ) ){
        return;
    }

    switch(index_load){
        case 0: $(id_section).load("/application/ajax/home.html",       load_home); break;
        case 1: $(id_section).load("/application/ajax/contact.html",    load_contact); break;
        default: $(id_section).load("/application/ajax/portfolio.html", load_portfolio);
    }
}

function load_home(){
    // about 180 lines of code
}

function load_contact(){
    // about 104 lines of code
}

function load_portfolio(){
    // about 95 lines of code
}
```

As you see, the functions *load_home, load_contact*, and *load_portfolio* are called before of obtaining the html of the section, and within them I have a initialization of several plugins (a lot of [select2](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), for example). And I want to create an event which shows an alert when all is initiated.

These are my questions:

1. There is a easy way to trigger this?
2. Is it worth to have already loaded all the html, and only call the function that initializes all when the user press the link in the menu?
3. Would be better have the code in separated js scripts and load them using `jQuery.getScript()` function?

Comment: The code, although you could refactor the way you're writing it using something like Angular, is fine. All your plugins are loaded once `load_home` has finished executing. The problem is that I'll bet each one of those third-party plugins has its own "loaded" event. You'd need to keep track of each "loaded" event for each plugin, then fire when all complete. Something which you could use promises for

Comment: Oh... I'm afraid select2 doesn't have the event in the documentation: http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation
What about the question number 2 and 3? Any tip or advice? Thanks :)

Comment: I wouldn't advise #2, although it would be fine for small amounts of code it's not very scalable (although since you're hardcoding load events it doesn't matter so much). I think if you're comfortable sifting through that large amount of code the way you have it is fine from a user perspective. Lastly, the event for `select2` is `select2-loaded` :)

Comment: Really thanks, I didn't realiced. :)

Comment: @RGraham, ´select2-loaded´ doesn't works. Look at this example: http://runnable.com/UmuP-67-dQlIAAFU/events-in-select2-for-jquery. Do you think `initSelection` is what I'm looking for? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Call these functions after the window has completed loading of all the html elements:

```
$(window).load(function(){
   load_home();
   load_contact();
   load_portfolio();
});
```

Comment: I think you don't understand the point of my question. This is only an example, imagine that I have 20 different sections. Would be a bad idea initializated ALL by default each time the page is loaded. And you suppose that I have the html loaded, but I don't. Please, read again the post. Thanks.